# How to use end time of script and use that as start time when running again the same script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

How to assign stop time as start time from 2nd run and further runs?

```
$start = currenttime;
while true;
./run_test.sh -input_param=$start
stop=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S --date "2018-03-12 01:45:55");
sleep 10;
done
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. Your date is fixed, `$stop` never used. Please clarify what you want to do.

Comment: `start=$stop` inside the loop should probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either store the date into memory for example into *tmpfs* filesystem like **(/dev/shm/lastexec.tmp)** or into disk like **(/tmp/lastexec.tmp)**.

Better to store the date to a temporary file on disk, because memory storage is volatile:

```
start="$(cat /tmp/lastexec.tmp)"
while true
do
./run_test.sh -input_param=$start
date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S --date "2018-03-12 01:45:55" > /tmp/lastexec.tmp
sleep 10
done
```

But with `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S --date "2018-03-12 01:45:55"`, the date won't change during the next script run because you have fixed it. The output will still the same `20180312014555`

Comment: start won't be updated on 2nd execution of the loop.

Comment: Yes but he means the second time he runs the script no within the loop iteration

Comment: Also the date is fixed it won't change maybe he is wrong !

Comment: thanks @RedaSalih, the Issue is fixed.